# Masonry load more using ajax in view using fuel cms

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, masonry, fuelcms

I am facing problem to perform ajax on custom module of **fuel CMS**. I want to load 5 more posts in blog post view using masonry effect. I want to perform using ajax request to load and append 5 more post. Can someone post a scenario to perform this task? If you are unfamiliar can read about masonry, please read here:

masonry effect: https://github.com/desandro/masonry

---

**Code for show masonry effect is like:**

```
<div class="blog-contents" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".blog-each"}'>
<?php foreach ($posts as $post) : ?>
<div class="col-sm-4 blog-each">
<?= $post ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: highlight important word in question.Add tag masonry.Spelling correction.

Comment: i think my question is clear there is no misunderstanding @VasimVanzara